# Trivial speedup of Grover to log(N) using interference?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

I have started to read more about Grover's algorithm to find the binary string $x'$ of $n$ bits for which $f(x=x')=1$ while $f(x\neq x')=0$, out of a total possibility space of $N=2^n$. So it works as

1. Prepare one uniform superposition of all posibilities ($O(1)$ with Hadamard gates)
2. A conditional phase flip gate $e^{i\pi f(x)}$, that gives a minus sign to $x'$ in the superposition.
3. A flip around the mean weight with a "diffusion operator"

By iterating steps 2 and 3, the weight of x' in the superposition would then keep growing, and achieve 50% probability on $O(\sqrt N)$ iterations.

So how about the following algorithm

1. Prepare two uniform superpositions $A$ and $B$ of all posibilities ($O(1)$ with Hadamard gates)
2. A conditional phase flip gate $e^{i\pi f(x)}$ to copy $A$, that gives a minus sign to $x'$ in the superposition. Leave $B$ invariant
3. Interfere $A$ and $B$ (such that it is destructive for all the non-flipped $x$), and then all weight goes to $x'$
4. Read out the interference pattern, scaling only as $O(n)=O(\log N)$ with photodetectors

This should in principle work in a single iteration. Why go through all the trouble of iterating with a diffusion operator?. I can imagine that it is hard to interfere qubits directly when thinking of them as spins, however that's only a technical limitation. Supperconducting qubits are just photons, so you should be able to let them interfere with each other in free space at least in principle.

More precisely, we could envision each of the qubits implemented in the manifold spanned by a pair of coherent states with opposite phases ie $|\uparrow\rangle=|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle=|-\alpha\rangle$, then, suppose that $x'=|\downarrow \downarrow\rangle$, we get $|A\rangle=-|-\alpha,-\alpha\rangle+|\alpha,-\alpha\rangle+|-\alpha,\alpha\rangle+|\alpha,\alpha\rangle$ while $|B\rangle=|-\alpha,-\alpha\rangle+|\alpha,-\alpha\rangle+|-\alpha,\alpha\rangle+|\alpha,\alpha\rangle$

If $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are now being emitted simultaneously from two spatially separated optical sources, their interference pattern will be of the form $|A\rangle+e^{i\phi}|B\rangle$, with $\phi$ spatially dependent. And we can choose it at a point in space where there is a half wavelength mismatch, then $\phi=\pi$. And at that point, the resulting state will be $|A\rangle-|B\rangle=-|-\alpha,-\alpha\rangle\propto|\downarrow \downarrow\rangle=|x'\rangle$ . It can be read out (the phases) using a homodyne detection scheme for each bit (we can always envision to use an extra spatial dimension or so to avoid different bits to interfere with one another).

Comment: Have you tried working your algorithm through on an example?

Comment: I agree with @Rammus . The easiest way for you to understand why this won't work is to experience it not working when you enter it into a simulator like https://algassert.com/quirk .

Comment: How would step 3 work?

Comment: @Rammus I have written it out explicitly for a simple case, extension to arbitrary large strings is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think step 3 needs some work. It's not clear how you close the interference between $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ as your state is $|A\rangle\otimes|B\rangle$ - $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are distinct photons. You can have a number of photons in $|A\rangle$ and you can flip the phase of one of the photons contingent on some other unitary $U$, but if $|B\rangle$ are other photons then you're still in a product state.

Comment: I have added a bit more specifics on what I mean. But no- indistinguishable particles in quantum physics, such as photons of the same frequency, constitute the same field so they can interfere. Just like you would see an optical interference pattern in a double slit experiment if you radiate each of the slits by a separate but identical laser.